# Issues in 20.04 with KDE/Plasma and nvidia cards

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, kde, plasma

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, all up to date, with KDE/Plasma and nvidia Quadro P620 card.

I have two monitors set up with two DELL U2717D monitors.

NVIDIA Driver is 450.80.02

My computer is always on, locked during night.

In the morning, when I come to work, I may find any of these:

1. blocked computer - only restart helps
2. dual monitor configuration gone (sometimes monitors are mirrored, sometimes second is disabled)
3. screen is garbled with dot grid or similar artifacts (sometimes <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> helps, sometimes not)

Tried to configure with system preferences, with nvidia X server setup app, saved setting so many times and everything works perfectly until first lock screen or after night.

This is happening all the time since I added this card to my computer, before that it was working good (with onboard chipset output).

I also think that since the driver upgrade the situation is worse, like, this happens more often than before with the old driver.

Any idea or insights?

EDIT:

Per request, I am adding some of my logs:

```
demsg.com | grep nvidia

[    0.844568] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    0.844575] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    0.849649] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    0.854661] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 238
[    0.855651] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    0.969246] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  450.80.02  Wed Sep 23 00:48:09 UTC 2020
[    0.969903] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    0.969905] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    3.291645] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 235.
[40396.154666] slack[4941]: segfault at 10 ip 00007fd989504ca0 sp 00007ffcb1fd7c60 error 4 in libnvidia-glcore.so.450.80.02[7fd988516000+133e000]
[41608.335589] QSGRenderThread[114552]: segfault at 89 ip 00007fde6ee5cb13 sp 00007fde6348a550 error 4 in libnvidia-glcore.so.450.80.02[7fde6e229000+133e000]
[217428.660873] [    676]   125   676     1297       37    49152        0             0 nvidia-persiste
[326745.172782] QSGRenderThread[308387]: segfault at 89 ip 00007efddae5cb13 sp 00007efdc5656770 error 4 in libnvidia-glcore.so.450.80.02[7efdda229000+133e000]


part of /var/log/Xorg.0.log

[400833.079] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2717D (DFP-0): connected
[400833.079] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2717D (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
[400833.079] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2717D (DFP-0): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.079] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2717D (DFP-2): connected
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2717D (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2717D (DFP-2): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.081] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal DisplayPort
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: disconnected
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: Internal TMDS
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[400833.083] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

This event in Xorg.0.log happens when I switch my monitors back on. Now I have same picture on both monitors, while yesterday (normal setup) I had expanded desktop over two monitors.

Comment: To solve this issue, I think more informations are required. Please connect your computer with another one via ssh, and investigate some logs such as `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `dmesg`.
They help you finding the cause of this issue.

Comment: I added some more info to the article with log extracts